# Where should I store OAuth client secret in an electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am building an electron app (desktop) that uses a public API. Now we all know that Javscript is going to be visible to all, and I am going to uglify my code.

To make API calls, I have to pass the client-id and the client-secret to the API provider. With these two keys anyone can impersonate me and call the API.

So far I've been using compiled programming environments, so getting to this info was harder. What do you recommend in this scenario, when I am using Javascript to create a desktop app, and the client secret is going to be there.

What can we do to make this work?

Sort of calling code on my own server to get this data, I can't think of any other way to store client secret securely.

Ideas please. :)

Comment: Did you come to a solution on ways to store secret like token in an Electron app?

Comment: I think that one way would be build your app to require the user to register and login through your app. Once authenticated your service/api can proxy the request to the third party service. I think apps like Postman do this, i.e. require login.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bytenode` for this: blackbox low-level API code and never export secret from blackboxed perimeter.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using any third party service/API, you cannot expose the client id and secret. You will have to route those requests via your own server. Also, few auth solutions check and validate the source/IP address of the requests. If such requests come from a random client IP, it might deny it altogether.

Comment: Doesn't this just fix the problem by creating another, identical problem? Now you need to secure access to your own server so bad actors don't call your server's proxy to the third party API. If you do this by passing a secret to your server, you now have store that secret in your electron app.